Show ON status as bad for a feature with the Red color or something else!
Here Ph ON is bad for the user so we are showing it with Red text, and icon. Ph Off status is good for the user so we are showing the text black. Is there any better approach to represent that or this one is easier for the user to understand the problem!


What are the doubts with the current design? Have you noticed any problems with it? Can you add more information about the context it is being used in?

My quick suggestions - use a WARNING icon (triangle with exclamation point) and make everything on the line red (switch name).

Thanks for the question.
I think the negative connotation of the meaning of ON and OFF used in the context might be creating the confusion.
Usually the colors are used based on the connotations of the verb/noun used in the context.
One good way to handle this situation is to take ahead the meaning by using only one variable. Either Color, Text or signage.
If your application has minimal accessibility issue go by color only.
Else icon is your good bet to proceed further as status.
Do let us know what is your final approach.! Appreciated.
